# Magento2 installSchema

Tags: magento2, install-script

I've create an install schema for a custom module. The problem is, that I put a field as foreign key but later it turned out I connected it to the wrong foreign field and table.

I've made the correct changes to the **InstallSchema** file and i want to run it again, but as iunderstand, the **InstallSchema file only runs once**. What is the best way to act in this situation ?

Comment: try by deleting it from setup_module table & it's table name. It is same as is equivalent of core_resource in Magento 1.

Comment: you can use UpgradeSchema.php

Comment: Arjun, thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, no UpdateSchema, nothing, just changed 2 rows in the installSchema, removed that row form the table you mentioned, runned setup:upgrade again and it worked, 10x a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update existing table/schema adding/updating row then,

**Step 1: Create UpgradeSchema.php under Setup folder. Get Idea from following code.**

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
class UpgradeSchema implements  UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) 
        {...}
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Step 2: Change the **setup_version** value in **module.xml**

Step 3: Run php **bin/magento setup:upgrade** command from CLI